# How well does my model fit? Specifying a null-model in non-linear mixed models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, goodness-of-fit

I want to fit a model `y ~ b * exp(-exp(a) * x)`, but including a random effect, with this data:

```
# data:
data = structure(list(re = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), levels = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    x = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), y = c(0.0899425978552549, 
    -1.85384333820306, -4.14514965495534, -1.81807449635766, 
    -1.35326955027327, -1.28825429472141, -0.209944981000945, 
    -2.55036342588007, -2.41329880502537, 1.60816564193517, 0.974291267956421, 
    -1.03569994133107, 0.259011545358077, 1.15202768590689, -1.11099110226214, 
    0.723503984838873, 1.0498337589214, 0.0331911544521152, -1.0534870983813, 
    -2.39106769323274, 0.145263217335939, -0.314587019845322, 
    1.27885667618699, -1.46171756397001, 0.69031827310659, 0.656834906437993, 
    0.0910321826159956, 1.59640958118439, 1.02260280171595, -0.0386924537729473
    )), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Thus I would fit this model with nlme:

```
# define the model function
f = function(x, a, b, Asym = 0) Asym + (b - Asym) * exp(-exp(a) * x)

# define the model:
model.1 <- nlme(y ~ f(x, a, b), 
               data =  d_pub,
               fixed = a + b ~ 1,
               random = b ~ 1 | re,
               start = c(b = -0.15, a = -0.7))

# model:
summary(model.1)

    # Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
    # Model: y ~ f(x, a, b) 
    # Data: d_pub 
    # AIC      BIC    logLik
    # 102.6748 108.2796 -47.33741
    # 
    # Random effects:
    #   Formula: b ~ 1 | re
    # b Residual
    # StdDev: 1.10461 1.095258
    # 
    # Fixed effects:  a + b ~ 1 
    # Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
    # a -0.6980492 0.6247593 26 -1.117309  0.2741
    # b -1.4309434 0.7840392 26 -1.825092  0.0795
    # Correlation: 
    #   a     
    # b -0.215
    # 
    # Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
    #   Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
    # -2.0549776 -0.5476474  0.1779084  0.9287772  1.8802465 
    # 
    # Number of Observations: 30
    # Number of Groups: 3
```

I would then also quickly look at the residuals:

```
plot(model.1)
qqnorm(resid(model.1)); qqline(resid(model.1))
```

If I look at the data (and the model prediction and the std error of the model parameters), I don't actually assume that this model is particularly good. In this particular case (although in other cases the model seems to fit quite well), it might even be possible that y doesn't depend on x at all.
To test this, I would like to compare it to a "null-model" to see whether it performs better or not.

Intuitively I would have fitted a linear model: `lme(y~1, data = data, random = ~1|re)`, but then I wouldn't know how compare these very different kinds of models!

Update: I have now fitted the null-model as following:

```
f2= function(x, a) a
model.0 = nlme(diff ~ f2(x, a),
                          data = d_pub,
                          fixed = a ~ 1,
                          random = a ~ 1|re,
                          start = c(a = mean(d_pub$diff)))
anova(model.1, model.0)
```

Is there any way to assess whether a nlme-model fits the data, some measure of gooness-of-fit? And are there practiacal ways to also test model assumptions for nlme-models?

Comment: You can use leave-one-out cross validation to compare the two models in terms of their predictive performance. Or alternatively Akaike information criterion (AIC). With AIC you'll have to face the question of how many parameters does the mixed model have. On a related note, there are three `re` groups in the example data. If this dataset is representative, it may be better to fit treat `re` as a fixed effect. See also [Why do random effects require a minimum # of levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/629864/237901)